# Extracting a mutable reference from an Option

Tags: rust

Is there any option to extract a mutable reference out of an `Option<&mut Foo>`?
All I found was `as_ref()` which extracts an immutable reference.

Comment: To get a mutable reference from an option, you use [as_mut](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_mut). But can you describe the case in which you intend to have a `&'static mut Foo` ?

Comment: `as_mut()` doesn't return a mutable reference, it just transforms a `&mut Option<Foo>` into `Option <&mut Foo>`. What I need is a why to extract `&mut Foo` out of `Option<&mut Foo>`..

Comment: `if let Some(r) = option {`?

Comment: Yeah that will  probably work I was wondering if there is a more idiomatic way with less boilerplate code

Comment: This boilerplate code has purpose of explicitly handing errors, and not ignoring them. If your functions are nicely structured and return `Option` or `Result` as well, then use `?` operator to extract your inner value without any boilerplate

Comment: If you know the `Option` is `Some`, then the unsightly`&mut **opt.as_mut().unwrap()` will extract `&mut Foo` out of `Option<&mut Foo>`. (The second `*` is to dereference `&mut &mut Foo`, and `&mut *` is the [explicit reborrow](https://github.com/rust-lang/reference/issues/788) that extracts the mut reference without moving it.) https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7af28c1073275a9232c08436b3c21e63

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there any option to extract a mutable reference outside of a `Option<&mut Foo>`.

Yes, but it requires a bit of effort to prevent consuming the `Option`, since `&mut T` is not `Copy`.

Let's assume you have an `Option<&mut Foo>` which is `Some`. (The same applies for a non-`Some` option, just replace `unwrap()` with appropriate matching.) For example:

```
let mut foo = Foo;
let mut opt = Some(&mut foo);
```

`opt.unwrap()` will give you `&mut Foo`, but it will *move* it out of the `Option`, because `&mut Foo` is not `Copy`:

```
let mut_ref = opt.unwrap();
drop(mut_ref);          // done with mut_ref
println!("{:?}", opt);  // XXX doesn't compile, opt is consumed
```

That will leave the `Option` unusable even after `mut_ref` is out of scope. We don't want that, we want to *borrow* the inside of the option and retain the use of the `Option` once that borrow is dropped. For that we can use `Option::as_mut`:

```
let mut_ref_ref = opt.as_mut().unwrap();
drop(mut_ref_ref);
println!("{:?}", opt);  // compiles
```

There are two things to note here: first, you need to use `as_mut()`, not `as_ref()` as you attempted, because `as_ref()` would give you a mutable reference behind a shared reference, which renders it useless. Second, unwrapping `as_mut()` returns an `&mut &mut Foo`, not the `&mut Foo` we wanted. It's very close, though - for example, auto-dereferencing allows you to call a function that accepts `&mut Foo`:

```
fn wants_ref(_r: &mut Foo) {}
let mut_ref_ref = opt.as_mut().unwrap();  // got &mut &mut Foo
wants_ref(mut_ref_ref);  // but we can send it to fn expecting &mut Foo
```

If you for some reason wanted an actual `&mut Foo`, one would think you'd get it by dereferencing the `&mut &mut Foo`. However, this doesn't work:

```
// XXX doesn't compile
let mut_ref = *opt.as_mut().unwrap();
```

That doesn't compile because `*` tries to dereference `&mut &mut Foo` and extract the underlying `&mut Foo`. But `&mut Foo` is not `Copy`, so that's attempting to "move out of a mutable reference", which rustc will tell you cannot be done. However, in this case it can, you need to perform an explicit [reborrow](https://github.com/rust-lang/reference/issues/788), i.e. turn `EXPR` to `&mut *EXPR`, where `EXPR` evaluates to a mutable reference. `&mut *EXPR` will create a *new* mutable reference to the same data. It doesn't count as aliasing because the old mutable reference will be (statically unusable) until the new one is dropped. It's basically the same mechanism that allows *projection* to work on mutable references (i.e. `let x_ref = &mut point.x`, with `point` being an `&mut Point`) - but applied to the object itself.

With explicit reborrow it looks like this:

```
// `&mut *` is reborrow, and `*` dereferences `&mut &mut Foo`
let mut_ref = &mut **opt.as_mut().unwrap();
wants_ref(mut_ref);
println!("{:?}", opt);  // opt is still usable
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=41ab2ed8a7cbac760a61ab32f577afbc)

Answer (score 2):

The correct way of doing that is through the `as_mut()` [method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_mut).

One tricky bit is that you need to satisfy the `&mut self` parameter type. The key observation is that if you own a `Option<&mut Foo>` value, you can safely turn into a `mut` version of the same (as you are the only owner of it).
That is, you can freely go from a `Option<&mut Foo>` (owned, immutable) to a `mut Option<&mut Foo>` (owned, immutable) and call the `.as_mut()` on that to reach the `&mut Foo` (reference, mutable).

So overall it looks like this:

```
let maybe_foo: Option<&mut Foo> = Some(&mut foo);

let mut maybe_foo = maybe_foo;
if let Some(mutable_reference_to_foo) = maybe_foo.as_mut() {
    ...
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f0e39a12756b7431dba88184353ea2a3)